# Is it a good idea to showing balance in transfer, confirmation and success screen

Tags: usability, user-research, user-centered-design, usability-study

I just want to understand the experience of showing the balance in any transfer, confirmation and success screen would make sense. If yes / no, what could be the down fall of it and reasons. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Is this a confidential information? Like if it's a bank balance, we wouldn't want it to be shown every time after a transaction, especially if someone's with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont want to see my balance when people are around me. So instead of showing balance you can ask them whether to show your balance. Something like

"Would you like to see your balance" "Yes" or "No"

or

"Show my Balance" "Yes" or "No"

So the user in control of whether to display the balance.

And regarding when to display the balance it is often good after the success screen so that user knows that the current transaction is over and they get a chance to know their balance, if needed.